# embedded web page on windows (7\ 8\ 8.1 ) desktop

Tags: windows, desktop, wallpaper

i was wondering if anyone knows how to embed a web page ( Or a web URL - as My Project is a WebApp) to windows desktop, not as a picture but a live embeded fixed size window ( as a part of the wallpaper i guess).

back on XP there was a tool called activedesktop but on win8 i am pretty lost ( on win 7 there was a poor ActiveDesktop gadget that Didnt do any good).

thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Web App Template** is a tool that uses your Web App as the core for a full featured Store App for Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8. The Web App Template (WAT) is implemented as a Visual Studio template that you install through our one click installer. You can then start a new project type of “Web App Template”. Plug your Web App values into the config file, and hit F5 to see it run.

http://wat.codeplex.com/